Variables not set in VBA excel
I'm trying to use VBA to view fields in a textbox taken from a spreadsheet.  That is working fine.  What I want to do, if I want to update said spreadsheet, i.e. I reviewed the text in the textbox but I want to add an update I want to be able to over right the text that is there and put it back in the same cell place within the spreadsheet.  I had this working fine on another spreadsheet I did years ago with the following code, but I must have done something else but I can't remember, and I can't find it in my code.
I used this code, and it previously worked, but its not working now, I've obviously forgot to do something.
Sheets("Table").Range("h1") = ComboBox3

Set r = Sheets("Data").Range("j9")
Set c = Sheets("Data").Range("j10")

Sheets("Table").Cells(r, c) = TextBoxtu.Value

Please help

Why not use Sheets("Table").Range("J9") = TextBoxtu.Value ?

Variable not defined sounds like you've got Option Explicit at the top of the sheet - which is a good thing, it stops you making new variables when you make a typo.  Just add Dim r as Range and Dim c as Range before those variables are used.

Cells expects row and column, so you will need to append .Row to r and .Column to c
Set r = Sheets("Data").Range("j9")
Set c = Sheets("Data").Range("j10")
Sheets("Table").Cells(r.Row, c.Column) = "111"


I'm afraid I still get the same "variable not define"

What is 'TextBoxtu'?
